# Tag merge: [Time] and [Timings]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I don't think that there is any difference between these two tag. : [time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [timings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timings). So can we merge these two tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T̺̘͡H͓E̹͎̰̲͕̝̬ ̖̙̪̭͞D̞̘Ę͚E̫̗͎D̹̬̞ ̥̹Ḥ̤͎A͍̲̮̮̠S̪̘͉͎̳ ̞ͅB̜͙̲̫̯̗E̱̞̗̫̥͝E̻̱̤̖̲͙͜N̜̗̗͚̬̻͟ͅ ̩̪̲̺͍͈͚͞D͇̗̖̬̠̭O͚̪͙̦N҉E̴͔̤̮̘̠ͅ.̻͉͟